# Adding more If statements for a simple javascript game

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie teaching myself how to code using a course through udemy.com. I'm in the process of learning Javascript and as a project we're instructed to created a simple Javascript game. Basically you enter a number that you think the computer is thinking. So far when you enter the correct number and click submit, a box will appear that states "Yay! That's exactly how many fingers I'm holding up!" or if it is not correct it will state "Sorry that's not correct, my number was .."

The problem is I can't figure out how to add additional if statements. For example I'm trying to alert a message that states "oops you need to enter a number" when the user clicks the submit button without entering a number or letter in the box. And when they've guessed the correct number of 0, the alert message will state "That's right, I have no fingers up!"

Here is the code that allows me to do the two instructions I listed above correctly:

```
<p>How many fingers am I holding up?</p>
<input id="answer"/>
<button id="myButton"><strong>Submit</strong></button> 
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick=function() {
    var x=Math.random();
    x=6*x;
    x=Math.floor(x); //use floor to get whole number

    if (x==document.getElementById("answer").value) {
        alert("Yay! That's exactly how many fingers I'm holding up!"); 
    } else {
        alert("Sorry that's not correct! My number was" + x );
    }
}
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Shereta, welcome to stackoverflow. You might get better responses if you worked on formatting your code so that it's a bit more readable. Check out the response [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for some tips on how to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a revised script, the problem was with the .value property. Please work on your indentation.

Follow this link for full code [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akinjide/6xycrjv6/1/)

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function() {
  var x = Math.random();
  var y = document.getElementById("answer");
  x = 6 * x;
  x = Math.floor(x); //use floor to get whole number

  if (y.value === "") {
    alert("Oops, you need to enter a number!");
  } else if (x == y.value) {
    if (x == 0) {
      alert("That's right, I have no fingers up!");
    } else {
      alert("Yay! That's exactly how many fingers I'm holding up!");
    }
  } else {
    alert("Sorry that's not correct! My number was " + x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Akinjide Bankole that solved my issue and yes I will definitely work on my indentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = Math.random();
x = 6*x;
x = Math.floor(x); //use floor to get whole number
var y = document.getElementById("answer").value;

if(y == null){
    alert("Please enter a number");
}else{
    if (x == y) {
        if(x == 0){
            alert("Yay! I'm not holding any fingers up!"); 

        }else{
            alert("Yay! That's exactly how many fingers I'm holding up!"); 
        }
    } else {    
        alert("Sorry that's not correct! My number was" + x );
    }
}
```